# How can I update a usermeta field using a dropdown in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, dropdown

I'm looking for help updating a usermeta field using a button. Or even better no button, just making my selection in the drop down. I'm listing all the users and their feilds in an array

```
$users = get_users( $args );
echo '<div class="user-list">';
echo '<table><tr><th>User ID</th><th>User Name</th><th>User Email</th> 
<th>Refund Status</th><th>Update Status</th></tr>';
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
echo '<tr><th>' . esc_html( $user->ID ) . '</th><th>' . esc_html( 
$user->display_name ) . '</th><th>' . esc_html( $user->user_email ) . 
'</th><th>' . '<select><option disabled>' . esc_html( $user- 
>refund_status ) . '</option><option value="Return Received">Return 
Received</option><option value="Refund Approved">Refund 
Approved</option><option value="Refund Sent">Refund Sent</option> 
</select>' . '</th><th><button class="button" 
onClick="updateStatus();"><span class="icon">Update Status</span> 
</button></th></tr>';
}
echo '</table></div>';
```

How can I get the button to update the refund status based on the selection made in the dropdown? The problem I'm running into is I don't know how to pass the variable and user id to Javascript foreach user to update the status. I've done a lot of reading but can't find what I'm looking for, maybe I'm wording my searches wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can call an onchange function on dropdown passing `userid` and `refund status`

```
function FunctionName(id, status) {

            var data = {
                'id': id,
                'status':status
            };
            //=========ajax==========//
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "update.php",
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                }
            });
            //=========End of ajax====//

}
```

somthing like this. in `update.php` you can run your query.

Comment: I copied and pasted this into a update.php file and have had no luck with this. I have since been trying to just make a simple form with a database connection to update metakey. So far no luck there either but I feel like I'm closer cause I understand it better. This example you gave me has left me very confused but I'd like to try to understand it. Could you help me make it work?